# How do I parameterize filtering a collection of Scala objects by type?

Tags: scala, reflection, types

Given a Scala collection containing items of variable types, I can filter by type.

```
trait X
case class Y(y:Int) extends X
case class Z(z:Int) extends X
val l = List(Y(1), Y(2), Z(3), Z(4))
l.collect{case e: Y=>e} // returns List[Y] = List(Y(1), Y(2))
l.collect{case e: Z=>e} // returns List[Z] = List(Z(3), Z(4))
```

I need to parameterize the filtering.

```
val f = Y
l.collect{case e: f=>e} // should return List[Y] = List(Y(1), Y(2))
```

The last line returns `error: not found: type f`. Parameterization of Scala types is not permitted in that `case` syntax.

Is there Scala-esque way to parameterize this filtering operation? (Perhaps using something other than the `collect` function.) Is reflection required?

Answer (score 1):

In `val f = Y` `Y` is not a type, but companion object.

You could use type like this:

```
type T = Y
l.collect{case e: T=>e} // returns List[Y] = List(Y(1), Y(2))
```

Or you could use companion object, but only for certain parameters count:

```
val t = Y
l.collect{case e @ t(_)=>e} // returns List[Y] = List(Y(1), Y(2))
```

In this case you should use `e @ t(_, _)` for `case class Y(y1:Int, y2:Int)`, `e @ t(_, _, _)` for `case class Y(y1:Int, y2:Int, y3:Int)` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assign a type itself to a val, but you can parametrize using a method type parameter:

```
def filterOnType[T : ClassTag](c: Traversable[Any]): Traversable[T] = {
  val tag = implicitly[ClassTag[T]];
  c.collect { case tag(t) => t } 
}
```

The `ClassTag` is used as a way to keep, at runtime, class information about `T`. Otherwise `T` would be erased, and `.collect { case t: T => t }` would be the same as `.collect { case t: AnyRef => t }`.

```
scala> filterOnType[Y](l)
res7: Traversable[Y] = List(Y(1), Y(2))

scala> filterOnType[Z](l)
res8: Traversable[Z] = List(Z(3), Z(4))
```

If you absolutely need to keep some representation of the type in a val, then keeping a `ClassTag` would work here. The `val` would have to be implicit for it to be picked up by `filterOnlyType`, or you could give it directly: `filterOnlyType[X](l)(myClassTagForX)`.