# Scala check at runtime whether an object has a the same type as a given parameterized type of a method invocation

Tags: scala, reflection, types

I have a type called T and some subclasses (forgive me if this is not the correct terminology) of T called T1, T2, T3, etc.

I want to write a method that

- takes in a collection of Ts
- takes (preferably as a type parameter of the method) a type S <: T
- returns the elements of the input collection that are of type S

The first approach that comes to mind is as follows, but it is defeated by runtime type erasure.

```
    elements.filter(_.isInstanceOf[S])
```

Can someone please provide some insight on what would be the simplest way to achieve this? Looking into this on Google suggests that it is doable by having my method take a `java.lang.Class` as an argument and doing runtime reflection with `java.lang.reflect` related classes. That seems like it is too generic, though.

That is to say, I know what type I want to filter for at the call site. I would ideally want to be able to call, say, something like `getInstancesOf[S]` because I statically know what S I want at the call site.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is `T` parameterized? If not, then there will be no type erasure.

Comment: To clarify, the type erasure that I'm worried about is on the method. `getInstancesOf[X]` and `getInstancesOf[Y]` need to do different things, but at runtime they have been erased to just be `getInstancesOf[Object]`. (Once again, please excuse the imprecise terminology here.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up finding the answer in [another StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16903706/3008170). I initially missed it because of how I was framing the question.

The outline of the answer is:

- The method takes an implicit ClassTag
- The compiler substitutes the appropriate ClassTag into the value of the implicitly call
- At runtime, the runtime class of the objects in question are checked against the ClassTag